# jupyter notebook で自作モジュールの読み込み方法

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookにて、自作した関数を入れた.pyファイルをimportしたいのですが、
importエラーが発生しており、エラー解決方法を教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、宜しくおねがいします。

フォルダ構造

(ルート)
├─read_own_script.ipynb
├─own_scripts
│  ├─__init__.py
│  ├─trans.py

read_own_script.ipynb

```
import sys, os
from pathlib import Path
#親ディレクトリのパスを取得,これはJupyter系特有の書き方
current_dir = os.path.join(Path().resolve())
# モジュールのあるパスを追加
sys.path.append(str(current_dir) + '/../')
from own_scripts import *
```

error code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-deb2ae9a92ca> in <module>
      5 # モジュールのあるパスを追加
      6 sys.path.append(str(current_dir) + '/../')
----> 7 from own_scripts import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'own_scripts'
```

`__init__.py`

```
from trans import *
```

trans.py

```
import pandas as pd

def trans_pd(a, b):
    return a + b
```

////////////////////以下追加/////////////////////////
以下に別途jupyter notebookにてsys.pathのprint出力し、中身を確認したときのコードを確認しました。

```
!pwd
```

output
`/c/Users/punch/Documents/Punch_data_analysis`

```
import sys, os
from pathlib import Path
# signalfuncなどのある親ディレクトリのパスを取得
current_dir = os.path.join(Path().resolve())
# モジュールのあるパスを追加
sys.path.append(str(current_dir) + '/../')

print(sys.path)
from own_scripts import *
```

output

```
['C:\\Users\\punch\\Documents\\Punch_data_analysis', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python38.zip', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', '', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\punch\\.ipython', 'C:\\Users\\punch\\Documents\\Punch_data_analysis/../']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d83d0f7d85f4> in <module>
      9 
     10 print(sys.path)
---> 11 from own_scripts import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'own_scripts'
```

Comment: この記事が該当するかも。[Import local function from a module housed in another directory with relative imports in Jupyter Notebook using Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34478398/9014308)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。頂いたリンク読んで回答にあった以下を実施したのですが、同様のエラーが発生し解決できませんでした。
追加コード
```
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```
おそらくこの記事は
sys.path.append(module_path)でpath追加して解決したよという記事だと思うのですが、私も同等のことをread_own_script.ipynbのsys.path.append(str(current_dir) + '/../')で実施しております。

Comment: 追加した結果をprint()等で確認してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: current_dir は確認したのでしょうか? 意図しているのは sys.path.append(str(current_dir)) じゃないのでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。大変申し訳ございません、ケアレスミスをしておりました。
ケアレスミス内容としては、.pyファイルは手元の端末のvscodeで、jupyterは別端末サーバーで実行しておりました。サーバーにてgit pullしてないため、own_scriptsフォルダがない状態でがんばってimportしておりました。

print(sys.path)や!lsを実施することで確認し、このケアレスミスに気が付きました。

Comment: 読み込みは上記方法で、own_scriptは読み込めたのですが、```__init__.py```の記述がすこし間違えていたので、そこを修正することで無事自作関数読み出せました。
間違えていた箇所は
```from trans import *```
を
```from .trans import *```
に変更です。